# How bad can $SK_1$ of a commutative ring be?

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, algebraic-k-theory

For a commutative ring $R$ define $\mathrm{SK}_1(n, R)=\mathrm{SL}(n, R)/\mathrm{E}(n, R)$, the quotient of the special linear group by its subgroup generated by the elementary matrices. When $n\geqslant3$, $\mathrm{E}(n, R)$ is normal in $\mathrm{SL}(n, R)$, and $\mathrm{SK}_1(n, R)$ is a group.

When $n$ is large compared to the stable rank of $R$, the group $\mathrm{SK}_1(n, R)$ is abelian. In general it is not. However, if the Bass—Serre dimension $\delta(R)$ is finite, $\mathrm{SK}_1(n, R)$ is nilpotent of degree at most $\delta(R)+1$ (BS-dimension is something very similar to the dimension the maximal spectrum).

It was shown by A. Bak ([PDF](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~bak/Nonabelian.pdf)) that the nilpotency degree can indeed be arbitrary large, and similar examples were constructed by W. van der Kallen ([link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404989900352)).

> **Question:** How bad can $\mathrm{SK}_1(n, R)$ be for a commutative ring $R$?

I'm interested in the examples of two kinds:

1. If $R$ is so and so, then $\mathrm{SK}_1(n, R)$ is not very bad;
2. Here's an example of $R$ such that $\mathrm{SK}_1(n, R)$ is terrible, e.g., perfect.

Comment: The examples of Bak and van der Kallen are commutative. So, what kind of example would you like for question 2?

Comment: @MatthiasWendt Explicit examples of commutative rings such that $\mathrm{SK}_1$ is far from being abelian, say, is perfect.